# python how to check answer of web browser

Tags: python, html, selenium, webresponse

I need help with python...
Do you know how I can check response of web browser after clicking button login (here: submit)?
I want to compare html code  and return True if my login will be a successful but unfortunately I don't know how. :/ Any hint would be priceless. :)
That's my code from selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.username").send_keys("margie")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.password").send_keys("margie")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn.submit").click()
```

Can I use "if"?

Thank you for your time guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can just continue using `driver` after clicking on `submit` button. For example, `driver.page_source` would contain the html code of the page displayed after the login.

There is no universal silver bullet to check if the login was successful or not. It depends on the web-site you are testing against: it may redirect to a particular url, have certain elements on the web page, certain title etc.

---

Just a side note. 
If you would follow [Page Object](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) pattern/concept, you would have a separate object for `Login Page` and a separate object for the page displayed after the login aka `Home Page` - like in [this example](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects#Example). The actual page look check after the login would be incapsulated inside the `Home Page` object realization which would make things clearer and better organized.

See also:

- [How to assert in selenium test case for login success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897377/how-to-assert-in-selenium-test-case-for-login-success)
- [Page Objects in Python](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-08/page-objects-in-python)